# Restful web services for mobile application(IOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I just want to know, which would be a better method for implementing restful web services(APIs) for mobile application. Is it better to have session over server or should user's log in credentials be passed before calling any other web service/API to ensure authentication.

In either case, if session is implemented being a mobile device user can log in for indefinite time and session takes memory but if I pass credentials it will going to be a repetitive process of authentication before calling any other service/API.

Please let me know your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use OAuth 2.0. You send the credentials (user and password) to the server which sends an authentication token back. Then you can use this token for the API calls. This is a safe way, because the authentication token can be refreshed or revoked anytime. See http://oauth.net/2/ for details.